# Why on trying to install ``storybook`` I get error as ``Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\nEW' command not found: storybook``?

Tags: reactjs, npm, storybook

I am trying to publish a react component library. For this, I want to install storybook.

My progress till now:
I made an empty folder. Ran npm init, and filled in all the details. A package.json file was created. I installed react and react-dom as dev dependencies.

Now that I want to install storybook using `npx storybook init` I am getting error as `Error: EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\nEW' command not found: storybook`.

I found a solution where it was mentioned to remove whitespace in the folder name. I realized that in `C:\Users` I am having a folder `nEW u` it has whitespace but I am unable to rename it to `nEWu`

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.